# Checking if data equal one of my file

Tags: php, file

I have a folder in my website, is it possible to check if a file exist for comparing with a data query ?

I mean if $donnees["DATA"] == one of the files of the folder.

I don't know any function or something about that.

For instance if Data = 25478

In my folder :

Differents name of file :

24788

24777

25478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$listOfFiles = glob("*");
if(in_array($donnees["DATA"], $listOfFiles) {
 //do stuff
}}
```

You can use glob("*.txt") for .txt files etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use  [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function:

```
//path to directory to scan
$directory = "somefolder/";

//get all folders/files in specified directory
$files = glob($directory . "*");

//get ach directory/file name
foreach($files as $file)
{
    if($donnees["DATA"]==$file){
        //do something
    }
}
```